# Password checker using do-while loop

Tags: java, loops, passwords, do-while

My friend's given question in our programming activity is

Write a fragment of code that will read words from the keyboard until the end the word "cherry" or "CHERRY" is entered. For each word except done, report whether its fist character is equal to its last character. For the required loop, use  do-while statement.

Example

Enter a word: mart
The first character is not equal to its last character: mart

Enter a word: tart
The first character is equal to its last character: tart

Enter a word: cherry
Program is now terminating...

```
package liniper;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Liniper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pass = "cherry";

        do{
            System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
            pass = in.nextLine();
        } while("cherry".equal(pass))
    } 
}
```

Comment: So you have a task, do it

Comment: We need to see that you have at least tried

Comment: We were not taught on how to do those first and last character thingies and I did try to search different ways to solve the problem, I was stuck on the while condition having String pass = "cherry" and I do not know what condition should I put. Sorry if you think its free loading, but we're struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String pass = "cherry"; // Defining the pass variable
    String word; // Defining the word variable
    boolean running = true; // Defining the running variable

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Making new Scanner Instance

    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a word: "); // Informing the User to enter a word
        word = scanner.nextLine(); // Retrieving the Word from Input

        char first = word.charAt(0); // Get the first character of the word by using the #charAt(int) method
        char last = word.charAt(word.length() - 1); // Get the second character by looking at the total length of the word and subtracting 1

        // Make the word lowercase and see if it matches the "pass" variable we defined
        if (word.toLowerCase().equals(pass)) {
            running = false; // Stop the loop
            System.out.println("The program is now terminating..."); // Informing the user that the program stops

            // Checking if the first character equals the last
        } else if (first == last) {
            // Informing the user that the first character is equal to the last last character
            System.out.println("The first character is equal to it's last character:" + word);
        } else {
            // Informing the user that the first character is not equal to the last last character
            System.out.println("The first character is not equal to it's last character:" + word);
        }
    } while (running);
}
```

I hope this can help you.